# Контекст данных в C#

Tags: xaml, wpf, c#

В своем приложении я задаю контекст данных через присваивания полю DataContext переменной отображения экземпляр контекста данных. Мне кажется, есть и другие способы его задания. Как задать контекст данных для отображения в xaml-разметке? Может есть другие способы задания контекста данных отображения?

Answer (score 6):

DataContext в XAML разметке может быть задан с помощью Binding-выражения. Вот пример установки контекста данных Grid'у от выбранного элемента в ListBox по событию SelectionChanged:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox, Path=SelectedItem}">
...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

В общем-то все способы сводятся к заданию этого свойства, только разными способами - DynamicResource, Binding, или явный.